# Find and replace regex term after manipulating it?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

What I want to do is this (in pseudocode):

```
search for [[phrase//<img src="example.jpg" />//description (if applicable)]]
replace with:
<a>phrase
<div>Description<br><img src="example.jpg"></div>
</a>
```

For example, I want to convert this:

```
[[transvaginal pudendal nerve block//<img src="3bc9e18a9fa82a1bd4e0c8c580909389.jpg" />//image of transvaginal pudendal nerve block]]
```

To this:

```
<a>transvaginal pudendal nerve block
<div>image of transvaginal pudendal nerve block<br><img src="3bc9e18a9fa82a1bd4e0c8c580909389.jpg" /></div>
</a>
```

Here's my code so far:

```
import re

answer_string = open("answer.txt", "r").read()
pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[.*\]\]")

for raw_material in re.findall(pattern, answer_string):
    copy_material = raw_material
    copy_material = copy_material.replace("[[", "")
    copy_material = copy_material.replace("]]", "")
    copy_material = copy_material.split("//")

    if len(copy_material) >= 3:
        raw_material = "<a>" + copy_material[0] + "<div>" + copy_material[2] + "<br>" + copy_material[1] + "</div></a>"
    else:
        raw_material = "<a>" + copy_material[0] + "<div>" + copy_material[1] + "</div></a>"

with open('new_answer.txt','w') as f:
  f.write(answer_string)
  f.close()
```

I thought that by setting `raw_material =` I would be able to instantly change the phrase, but I guess not. Kind of confused as to how I can find something with regex, manipulate it, then replace the phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use `re.sub` to substitute matches, and you can call a little function if your replace string might be different in different cases.  For example:

```
def replace_string(matchobj):
    if len(matchobj.groups()) == 5:
        if matchobj.group(5):
            return "<a>"+matchobj.group(2)+"\n<div>"+matchobj.group(5)+"<br>"+matchobj.group(3)+"</div></a>"
        else: 
            return "<a>"+matchobj.group(2)+"\n<div><br>"+matchobj.group(3)+"</div></a>"
    else:
        return ""

pattern = re.compile(r"\[\[((.*?)//)(.*?)(//(.*?))*\]\]")

print re.sub(pattern, replace_string, answer_string)
```

Now, this is quick and dirty but the idea is that the `re.sub` will find and replace *all* matches.  I changed the pattern to add the parenthesis, which makes Python 'capture' the matches into the match object's `groups()`.  So based on the added parenthesis, there are 5 capture groups.  I think there will be 5 capture groups every time this expression matches, but if something doesn't match, the captured group will be `None`.

When the substitution happens, it calls the `replace_string` function, and the code decides what to return based on whether the 5th group is `None`. That'll happen if the `//description` part is omitted.  I'm not sure if the check for 5 groups is necessary, but wanted to be sure.

Anyway, I think this should point you in a helpful direction at least.

Comment: Thank you so much! This means so, so much to me.